# Apache flink timeouts handling in RichAsyncFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using flink of 1.5.0 version.

Official doc says :

`Timeout Handling
When an async I/O request times out, by default an exception is thrown and job is restarted. If you want to handle timeouts, you can override the AsyncFunction#timeout method.`

1 - In fact when timeout exception happens there is no any notion in logs (any level) and job is not failing.

2 - There is no method timeout in AsyncFunction interface :)

Why that concerns me ->

I use AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait which consumes from the kafka and handles result with RichAsyncFunction. In fact all messages were read (correct offset was committed to zookeeper) but not all of them reached RichAsyncFunction.asyncInvoke.
Since it does not log timeout exceptions I'm just wondering maybe it swallows (does not show) other exceptions as well.

Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I found the reason :

AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait consumes from the stream and passes elements to the 
RichAsyncFunction wrapper. But elements from the stream won't be passed to the asyncInvoke if RichAsyncFunction.open method is still being executed and elements are silently dying after timeout passed to the unorderedWait.